# "input" element that created by AJAX can't detect by another javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, input, jscolor

We are using http://jscolor.com (JavaScript Color picker) without any problem normally. But when we create the input element by AJAX, it don't work correctly and jscolor.js can not detect class (color) of the input, while the input show correctly. What we should do?

The HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='/js/jscloro.js'></script>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="showHint('jscolorpicker')">FORM</a>

<div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Our PHP response to ajax is:`echo "<input class=\"color\" type=\"text\" value=\"66ff00\">";`

Comment: Please post the code that does the insertion.

Comment: @orique; the HTML code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, when you create new `DOM` element after `document`load, you should bind the event's after where you create that's element.

**UPDATED PART OF ANSWER**
See this html and script:

`<div id="container"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // if you add the event for element that currenlty not exist on
        // page, and later may be created, the even cannot fired
        $('#elem').click(function () {
            alert('You are clicked on input!');
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'somePage.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application;json/ charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {

                // if you create your own element here
                $('#container').append(function () {
                    return $('<span>')
                        .text('This Is New Element')
                        .attr('id', '#elem');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

But the correct way is to add `event` after where `DOM` element is created, as you see below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somePage.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application;json/ charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {

                // if you create your own element here
                $('#container').append(function () {
                    return $('<span>')
                        .text('This Is New Element')
                        .attr('id', '#elem')
                        .click(function () { // you should bind your events here
                            alert('You are clicked on input!');
                        });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATED PART 2**

you should initialize the new jscolor instance, for example use this code

```
new jscolor.color($('.color'), {});
```

after you created your own element.

**UPDATED PART 3**

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src='/js/jscloro.js'></script>
    <script>
        function showHint(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    /* YOU SHOULD INITIALIZE THE NEW JSCOLOR INSTANCE HERE */
                     var myPicker = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('myField1'), {})
                     myPicker.fromString('99FF33') // 
                    /**/
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showHint('jscolorpicker')">FORM</a>

    <div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

*Please mark it as answer if it helped you.*

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain more? Please edit our code.

Comment: No. See our codes again. the 'input' created by PHP, not JAVASCRIPT or JQUERY. All elements of form created by PHP file and returned into 'txtHint' DIV that the '.color' input is one of this form elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Can you please insert your updates in our codes and write it?

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But how we can initialize our new jscolor instance? What should be our PHP output? Did you see the jscolor.com? There is no script for index.html, you should just load jscolor.js in your HTML code.

Comment: I'm getting to be confused. What is the your `PHP` output now?

Comment: Hi. I found the solution. It don't work with class, you should put this instead "new jscolor.color....." :

var myPicker = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('myField1'), {})
myPicker.fromString('99FF33')  // now you can access API via 'myPicker' variable

Comment: Edit your code please to i mark it as answer. Kheyli mamnoon ;)